# tikz: Rotating and positioning text relative to a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, text

This code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
    \path (0, 0) edge node [sloped, anchor=center, below] {line}(3, 3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the output

[image]

The text has the orientation and placement exactly as needed relative to the line which has been drawn by some other method:

```
 \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointxy{0}{0}};
 \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointxy{3}{3}};
 \pgfusepath{stroke}
```

Hence, I need only the text and not the line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: +1 Good MWE - I linked a question that seems like a duplicate to me (rotate a node).

Comment: `\path (0,0) -- (3,3) node [pos=0.5,sloped, anchor=center, below] {line};`

Comment: By the way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided/42115#42115

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[red]  (0,0) edge node[below,sloped] {line} (3, 3);
        \path       (0,0) to [pos=0.4, sloped, "line" '] (3, 3);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  every edge quotes/.append style = {anchor=north, sloped}
                     ]
        \path[red]  (0,0) edge node[below,sloped] {line} (3, 3);
        \path       (0,0) to ["line"] (3, 3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(as supplement to [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) comment). positioning of edge labels is little bit tricky when it is in `sloped` orientation. in such cases, if you require exactly centered labels, you have three possibilities:

- play with manual tweaking of label position (showed in top image)
- redefine edge labels style (bottom image)
- use edge nodes (in image below is in red color, but with visible line for better orientation where are labels)

[image]

Comment: I think one cannot forget `pos`, `anchor` and `below`.

Comment: Could you add these details to your answer?

Comment: @Viesturs, see edited answer.